# htaccess redirect from folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, proxy

I'm trying to phrase a url that would look simmular to this:

```
http://foo.domain.com/bar/fee/
```

to this:

```
http://IP:port/bar/fee/
```

This is my current code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.domain.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://IP:port/$1 [P]
```

But this is not working, hence this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match `path segment` in `HTTP_HOST` variable.

Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://IP:port/$1 [P]
```

If you don't want `proxy` feature then replace `P` flag:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://IP:port/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Just pust me to my regular domain.

Comment: Edited again, I suggest using 2nd rule with `R=301`

Comment: I am still having no success. I am using cloudflare on my site, can this have an effect? Or can i be missing something in my setup?

Comment: Did you use 2nd version of the rule? Do you have some other rules also in this .htaccess OR is there any other .htaccess file?

Comment: There is only one other thing in my .htaccess, which is `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php` because i had some issues with this before, and yes i am using the 2nd rule

Comment: So what URL are you using to test this?

Comment: No. It seems like my .htaccess file still does not take in action

Comment: what URL are you using to test this?

Comment: If you want answers to your problem at least be prompt in your responses.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41126/discussion-between-peacedealer-and-anubhava)